# Особенности nil в Delphi

Tags: delphi, null

nil в Delphi - тоже самое, что null в других языках?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Константа   **Nil** Значение не присвоенного указателя

Переменная  **Null**    Переменная, которая не имеет никакого значения

Comment: переменная Null?

Answer (score 5):

`null` в каждом из языков имеет немного разную семантику. Например, разыменование `nullptr` в C++ -- это undefined behaviour. Разыменование `null` в C# -- гарантированный `NullReferenceException`. В Objective C отправка сообщения `nil` -- законная операция, просто ничего не происходит. Немного выбивается из общей линии SQL: там `NULL` -- это не ссылка, а дополнительное "пустое" *значение* у типа данных.

Но в общем и целом да, `nil` -- это "пустой" указатель, как и `null`.

Comment: По поводу ничего не происходит Вы не совсем правы, если метод должен что-то вернуть то он вернет nil, ну и плюс в obj-c еще присутствует NSNull - класс-обертка над nil, ну и куча других констант, на хабре недавно статья была http://habrahabr.ru/post/165021/

Comment: @aknew: да, вы правы, я немного упростил, чтобы более выпукло показать разницу между поведением `nil` в Objective C и `null` в C#. Спасибо за дополнение!